# Please set available and/or protected paths list(s) before validation. | Create sitemap

Tags: adminhtml, catalog, xml, sitemaps

I'm trying to create a Google Sitemap through: **Catalog > Google Sitemap**.

**Filename:** sitemap.xml
**Path:** /sitemap
**Store View:** Nederlands

(I have two store views).

The path **/sitemap is writable** (chmod -R 777).

The problem is when I want to save & generate I get the following error:

```
Please set available and/or protected paths list(s) before validation.

Trace:
#0 /home/company/domains/companyit.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php(138): Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_AvailablePath->isValid('/sitemap/sitema...')
#1 /home/company/domains/companyit.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_SitemapController->saveAction()
#2 /home/company/domains/companyit.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#3 /home/company/domains/companyit.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /home/company/domains/companyit.be/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/company/domains/companyit.be/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/company/domains/companyit.be/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

**UPDATE :**

In my app/local/Mage folder I have the following: (no configuration files)

[image]

Comment: Which Magento version are you running? Do you have any files in `app/code/local/Mage`?

Comment: @mam08ixo: I'm running version 1.7.0.2 . I've got 4 folders in app/code/local/Mage: Adminhtml / Core / Eav / Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Since CE 1.5.1.0, Magento has a configured list of filesystem paths that may be exposed to the public. Valid paths for the sitemap files are derived from the configuration nodes [`general/file/sitemap_generate_valid_paths`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml#L192) and [`general/file/public_files_valid_paths`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml#L402).

In a standard Magento CE 1.7.0.2, the reported error cannot occur.

That means, your installation has a modified core. Common ways of changing core behaviour include using observers and applying class rewrites.

Additionally, core files can be altered directly or be replaced using *code pool overrides*. At the latest when an installation is about to be upgraded, these types of modifications will lead to errors and thus are considered bad practice. *Code pool overrides* are established when files from `app/code/core/Mage/` are copied to `app/code/local/Mage/`. Files that reside in the latter directory supersede the original core files. There are very rare situations when *code pool overrides* are the only way to solve an issue – still, as per your comment, they were applied.

So I assume there are configuration files `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml` and `app/code/local/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` in place that lack the necessary configuration nodes mentioned above. The paths not being available then leads to the given error message `Please set available and/or protected paths list(s)`. In order to solve your issue, you could just copy the configuration nodes from the CE 1.7 core files. But as a long-term solution, to avoid further situations like this, I strongly advise you to get rid of all the *code pool overrides* in the installation.

**UPDATE:**

According to the given directory tree, the *code pool overrides* do neither include any `config.xml` files nor core classes responsible for reading these values. Still, the original config nodes fail to be read. You can now debug your installation:

- [Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Catalog::getSitemapValidPaths()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog.php#L101)
- [Mage_Core_Helper_Data::getPublicFilesValidPath()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php#L794)
- [Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_AvailablePath::setPaths()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/AvailablePath.php#L119)

Magento CE 1.7.0.2 shipped with Mage_Core 1.6.0.2 – Your version 1.6.0.0 is a little unusual but that should not make a difference here.

Besides, the usual hints:

- Compiler off
- Cache cleared
- No invalid entries in the `core_config_data` table for these two configuration nodes

Comment: I've updated my topic. I don't have any configuration files in my app/local folder .. . Could you take a look?

Comment: Please expand `Adminhtml`, too. Do you have any files in `app/code/community/Mage`? What version numbers are given in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml` and `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml`? Do these files contain the configuration nodes I suspected to be missing?

Comment: In app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml: 0.7.1 and in app/code/coreMage/Core/etc/config.xml: 1.6.0.0 . These file do actually contain the nodes ... . And I don't have any files in app/code/community/Mage .. + Updated my topic with the new image (Adminhtml expanded)

Comment: Answer updated. Honestly I run out of ideas.